# How to merge two array and sum their value?

Tags: javascript

There are two array and i want to merge two array and sum their only if data name is matched.Otherwise merge only or push array if name is not matched

```
var demo = {
    "key1": [{"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
                   {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
                   {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}],

    "key2": [
                 {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
                 {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
                 {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1},
                 {"id":4, "name": "Alvida", "kill": 8 , "knock": 5}]
};
```

This is my script file

```
var res = demo.key1.map(function(item, idx) {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(obj, key) {
        if (key == 'name') {
            obj[key] = item[key];
        } else {
            obj[key] = item[key] + demo.key2[idx][key];
        }

        return obj;
    }, {});
});
console.log(res);
```

My result is like this

```
0:  {id: 1, name: "Robbie", "kill: 24 , knock: 5},
1:  {id: 2, name: "Mohamand","kill: 25 , knock: 7},
2:  {id: 3, name: "Jebisha", "kill: 13 , knock: 5},
```

My expected output is like this

```
0:  {id: 1, name: "Robbie", "kill: 24 , knock: 5},
1:  {id: 2, name: "Mohamand","kill: 25 , knock: 7},
2:  {id: 3, name: "Jebisha", "kill: 13 , knock: 5},
3:  {"id":4, "name": "Alvida", "kill": 8 , "knock": 5}
```

Comment: can you guarantee the order and position in each array will match?

Comment: i want to sum only if both array name match otherwise just merge or push aray

Comment: is the position in the array guaranteed between the two arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the last element because you only iterate the first array and search for matches in the second one, but "Alvida" only exists in the second array. So what you need to do is iterate over both arrays while constructing a new one. If in the new array a property already exists, you sum the values, if not you create it.

Illustrative example:

```
const results = {};
// arrayToInspect is key1, key2
Object.keys(demo).forEach(function(arrayToInspect) {
  demo[arrayToInspect].forEach(function(element) {
    if (results[element.name]) {
      results[element.name].kill += element.kill;
      results[element.name].knock += element.knock;
    }
    else {
      results[element.name] = element;
    }
  });
});
```

Then if you need it as an array you can just do:

```
const resultsArray = Object.values(results);
```

Comment: yes and if put second array at the top.then error will come.so Can you give example please

Comment: Added example :) Edit: I had a typo at the second forEach - it's now been fixed.

Comment: Errory is "arrayToInspect.forEach is not a function"..

Comment: That's what I fixed hehe If you copy it again it should work. Anyway I tried to use the same syntax you were using but if that is not a concern, Sajeeb Ahamed's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

1. Use map the gather data then calculate the sum
2. Use [key, value] to iterator the map to build array

```js
var demo = {
    "key1": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Robbie",
            "kill": 12,
            "knock": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mohamand",
            "kill": 12,
            "knock": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Jebisha",
            "kill": 8,
            "knock": 4
        }
    ],
    "key2": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Robbie",
            "kill": 12,
            "knock": 4
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Mohamand",
            "kill": 13,
            "knock": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Jebisha",
            "kill": 5,
            "knock": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Alvida",
            "kill": 8,
            "knock": 5
        }
    ]
};

function merge(demo) {
    let map = new Map()

    let _calculate = function cal(arr) {
        for (const item of arr) {
            if (!map.has(item.id)) {
                map.set(item.id, {id: item.id, name: item.name, kill: 0, knock: 0})
            }
            const obj = map.get(item.id);
            obj.kill += item.kill
            obj.knock += item.knock
            map.set(item.id, obj)
        }
    }

    Object.keys(demo).forEach(key => {
        _calculate(demo[key])
    })
    
    let arr = []
    for (const [key, value] of map) {
        arr.push(value)
    }
    return arr;
}


console.log(merge(demo));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Object.keys(demo).reduce` to go over every `demo` key.
2. `demo[key].map` to iterate over the data of each `"key"`.
3. If the data exists => sum the `kill` and `knock`, otherwise => add it.

Here you go :D

```js
let demo = {
  "key1": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Robbie",
      "kill": 12,
      "knock": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mohamand",
      "kill": 12,
      "knock": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Jebisha",
      "kill": 8,
      "knock": 4
    }
  ],

  "key2": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Robbie",
      "kill": 12,
      "knock": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mohamand",
      "kill": 13,
      "knock": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Jebisha",
      "kill": 5,
      "knock": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Alvida",
      "kill": 8,
      "knock": 5
    }
  ]
};

let ans = [];
Object.keys(demo).reduce((acc, key) => {
  demo[key].map(data => {
    let found = acc.find(d => d.id === data.id);
    if (found) {
      found.kill += data.kill;
      found.knock += data.knock;
    } else {
      acc.push(data);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, ans);

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Here it doesn't matter there are how many keys. And as you are maintaining an object for checking if the named object exists or not so it is faster.

```js
var demo = {
    "key1": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
        {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}
    ],
    "key2": [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
      {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
      {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1},
      {"id":4, "name": "Alvida", "kill": 8 , "knock": 5}
    ]
};

const res = {};

Object.values(demo).forEach(items => items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (res[curr.name] !== undefined) {
    res[curr.name].kill += curr.kill;
    res[curr.name].knock += curr.knock;
  } else {
    res[curr.name] = curr;
  }
  return res;
}, res));

const result = Object.values(res);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const demo = {
"key1": [{"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
               {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
               {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}],

"key2": [
             {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
             {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
             {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1},
             {"id":4, "name": "Alvida", "kill": 8 , "knock": 5}]
};

const res = Object.values(demo).reduce((acc, value) => {
const currentElements = value;
currentElements.forEach((el) => {
    if (!acc[el.id]) {
        acc[el.id] = el
    } else {
        acc[el.id] = {
            ...acc[el.id], 
            "kill": acc[el.id]["kill"] + el["kill"],
            "knock": acc[el.id]["knock"] + el["knock"],    
        }
    }
});
return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```